# Delphi app freeze when open another app in second monitor

Tags: freeze, monitor, rdp

NOTE 1: My app is compiled in Delphi XE2 and in Delphi 10.2 with the same behavior.

NOTE 2: This behavior occurs only by running my application from a server using an RDP environment, in local environment it does not occur.

I run a process with a simple "For" cycle, in my app that lasts a few minutes,(showing on the first monitor), if during the execution of that process, I switch to another app on a second monitor (for example Excel, inside or outside the RDP, no matter), when returning to my app on the first monitor, my app appears frozen and there is no way to get the focus back for as long as I click on it, and the only way to close it is from the TaskManager, where it appears as Not responding.

I tried to set the focus to my app in the Application.OnActive event, also intercepting the WM_ACTIVATE message, without any positive results.
I tried also using a TTimer to display feedback to screen in my app to check if the TTimer thread is frozen as well, and yes, it freezes as well.

Comment: To to add logs on events OnError, OnActivate, OnDeactivate for forms and application. Also check Application.ModalLevel property. It's seems that you have modal form with broken Z-order. Windows broke Z-order when your application does not response for  4 seconds